# Migrating from Swagger 1.5 to 2.0 - Annotations alternative

Tags: swagger, openapi, swagger-2.0

We are migrating from Swagger 1.5 to Swagger 2.0 . I found one link which helped me with process to some extent [Link](https://www.david-merrick.com/2017/11/15/useful-regexes-for-transitioning-swagger-2-0-to-3-0-annotations/)

Though i have few problems :

```
@ApiModelProperty(value = "Some text", position = 1) and @ApiModel are now 

@Schema(description ="Some text")
```

i did not find the alternative for following attributes of @ApiModelProperty in @Schema annotation

- position
- notes
- dataType

and for `@ApiModel(value = "somevalue", parent = Parent.class)`
I did not find any method/similar method under Schema Interface for parent as well.

what could be the possible alternative for

position
notes
dataType and
parent

in Schema Interface ?

Could anyone help me with that ?
Thanks